# Big Cartel - Luna 2x2 Product Home Page

Tags: html, css, themes, product, bigcartel

I was trying to make my home page have a 2x2 grid of images. 
There was a thread with a similar question already. The answer was to include this code:

```
#home_page .canvas {
max-width: 590px;
}
```

I did this and it kicks my footer over to the left. I went into the CSS and tried under every footer mention I could find to include text-align: center; code although to no avail. I also tried playing with the 590px, but it moves the images over and no longer centers them.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is a link to my page: http://johnathonpowers.bigcartel.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the

```
float:left;
```

property from the

```
#site_footer footer {

}
```

CSS class and it should all work fine for you.

In essence, you #site_footer footer class should look like this:

```
#site_footer footer {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 900px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You #site_footer footer class currently looks like this:

```
#site_footer footer {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 900px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 65px auto 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What can be the reason to have both `width` and `min-width` properties (that too with wide differences in values). Keep one width property value (either `width` or `min-width`). Similarly, why `float` after `clear`? Understand that `clear` is used to remove any previous floats. If you want to continue floating, there's no reason to write `clear: both`

Hope this helps!!

EDIT: Please see the screenshots below!!!!

[#site_footer footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4VN.png)

[#site_footer footer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkp1x.png)

If you remove the float:left, your footer div will be centered.
In case you can't do it, you can overwrite the float:left property in your CSS file as such:

```
#site_footer footer {
float:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Will try this later when I have the time.

Comment: Hmmmmm....ok this is what I see in my CSS.

`/* Structure
------------------------------------------------------------*/

#site_footer footer {
  min-width: 0;
  float: none;
 }`

Comment: So comments can only be editted for 5mins and 500 characters. Silly. 

`/* Site Footer
------------------------------------------------------------*/

#site_footer footer {
  min-width: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  }

#site_footer footer h3 {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

#site_footer ul {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid {{ theme.borders }};
  }`

Comment: continued....

`#site_footer li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid {{ theme.borders }};
  font-family: {{ theme.body_font | font_family }};
  }

#site_footer li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  }

#site_footer footer p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  }

#site_footer #search input {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  }`

And how frustrating that enter submits the comment! Also, sorry I cannot figure how to add a break.

Comment: Did you remove the float:left property from the "#site_footer footer" CSS class?

Comment: No it never existed. Sorry but I did not write 99.9% of the CSS code. It was all generated by Big Cartel/the theme. 

I merely added that code in my original question to the very end of the CSS coding. Upon doing that my footer is no longer centered. When I remove it, my footer is centered again. What I pasted in the comments is the only footer sections I can find in the CSS section of my website.

Comment: Still no luck. I do not see float:left anywhere in the CSS coding.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please take a look at the edited section.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help and time. I am really sorry, but after 30mins of searching that code just does not exist in what I am seeing. Perhaps Big Cartel outputs something different when you view the source then what is in front of me. This is what I see. http://imgur.com/ls1SloE

Comment: Don't feel sorry. Its ok. We all go through it :).. Can you try adding #site_footer footer { float:none !important; } class to your code. I think maybe the property is being inherited from somewhere or maybe its being added dynamically via some script. Please add this to the very bottom of YOUR CSS file and see what happens.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. Thanks a ton! Your patience is amazing. I felt embarrassed joining this site and asking questions, since in all honesty I probably should have just hired someone more experienced to do all this for me. Slowly it is coming along. Now to figure out a picture slideshow thingy for my product pages....another question coming soon haha. Thanks again and have a great weekend.

Comment: Well, happy to help. By the way if you are planning to hire someone to do this for you, well, you could hire 'yours truly' :)..Haha!!..Have a great weekend and hope your site comes out really well!!!

Comment: Thanks for the information and definitely will let you know if I end up going down that road.